# Use DataFrame index as x-axis ticks

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with an Index (Time) and one column (Rate). I'd just like to use the Time as the x-ticks in a histogram plot and Rate as the y axis.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rates,orient='index')
data.index.name = 'Time'
data.columns = ['Rate']
data.plot(kind='hist', x = data.index.values)
```

`print(data)` produces:

```
          Rate
Time          
0     1.191309
1     1.208280
2     1.244835
3     1.279342
4     1.307912
5     1.532720
```

Comment: Try this: `data.plot.hist()`

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything

Comment: What exaclty do you want to plot and what is your current problem/issue?

Comment: I just need a histogram plot where the y axis is the 'Rate' and the x axis is the 'Time'. At the moment what I have now is giving me this http://puu.sh/uXT1s/579adee755.png
Appreciate the help, Max.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up `hist` plot and `bar` plot? Do you need bar-plot: `data.plot.bar()`?

Comment: Yep that was it, it's all good now. Thanks

Comment: @JasonH pls remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
```

Source DF:

```
In [122]: data
Out[122]:
          Rate
Time
0     1.191309
1     1.208280
2     1.244835
3     1.279342
4     1.307912
5     1.532720
```

[Bar-plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
In [126]: data.plot.bar(rot=0)
Out[126]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xe1fe048>
```

[image]

[Histogram plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html):

```
In [131]: data.plot.hist(rot=0)
Out[131]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xe7611d0>
```

[image]